# Apply tags in a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I need some help tag-related!

I am writing a simple editor, supporting basic formatting. 
By using a Text widget (named *text*), I put a tag 'b' to set the text where this tag applies to bold.

This is not a problem when I apply the bold to a selection:

```
text.tag_add('b', SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
```

I have instead two problems when I just want to switch on/off the bold while typing.
To switch it on the only way I found is this:

```
text.insert(INSERT, '  ', 'b' )
text.mark_set("insert", INSERT+'-1c')
```

notice that I have to insert TWO spaces. If I insert one, the bold doesnt apply. If I insert '', my cursor goes back one char!

My second problem is how to switch it off, when I'm writing within a bolded region - and for this I havent the slightest idea...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not realize it, but you're trying to do something that's very hard in Tkinter. While the text widget tags are a powerful concept, they have some weaknesses when it comes to creating something like a wysywig editor.

You need to change your approach a bit. Instead of inserting spaces, I think the better solution is to add bindings that apply (or remove) your tags each time a character is inserted. This has it's own set of problems, but with enough attention to detail you can overcome them. We can do that though a custom key binding.

When you insert a character into a text widget, this is handled by a binding on the `<Key>` event on the text widget class. So, we could bind to `<Key>` to add the tag. However, if we add a binding to `<Key>` on the widget, this will fire *before* the class binding, meaning our code will execute before the character inserted rather than after. We'll be trying to modify something that hasn't actually been inserted into the widget yet.

One way to solve that is to bind to a key *release* rather than a key press, since the character is inserted on the press. However, think of the scenario where a user presses and holds a key down -- multiple characters will be entered but you may only get a single key-up event. So this solution isn't particularly good.

Another solution is to somehow arrange for our custom binding to happen *after* the default binding. To do that we need to do two things: 1) adjust the "bind tags" for the widget to have an additional tag after the class tag, and 2) add a binding to this new bind tag.

There are downsides to this approach too. Not because of the bind tags, but because there are a lot more events you need to handle besides `<Key>` (for example, control-v to paste isn't handled by the `<Key>` binding, so you'll have to add a special case for pasting).

That being said, this solution might be good enough for you, or at least good enough to help you better understand the problem, and understanding the problem is often the biggest obstacle to finding a solution.

In the following example I have a text widget that has an additional bindtag named "CustomText" that we place after the standard "Text" bind tag. I put a binding on this tag for the `<Key>` event, and in the handler I simply apply the appropriate tags to the just-inserted character.

You'll have to add your own code to handle a clipboard paste, and the problem of dealing with conflicting tags (such as two tags each with their own font). Hopefully, though, this example will act as inspiration

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tag_vars = {
            "underline": tk.IntVar(),
            "red": tk.IntVar(),
            }

        self.text = MyText(self, width=40, height=8)
        self.text.tag_configure("red", foreground="red")
        self.text.tag_configure("underline", underline=True)

        toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        self.underline = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Underline", 
                                        onvalue = True, offvalue=False,
                                        variable = self.tag_vars["underline"]
                                        )
        self.red = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Red", 
                                  onvalue = True, offvalue=False,
                                  variable = self.tag_vars["red"]
                                  )
        self.underline.pack(in_=toolbar, side="left")
        self.red.pack(in_=toolbar, side="left")

        toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class MyText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent

        # add a new bind tag, "CustomText" so we
        # can have code run after the class binding
        # has done it's work
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        i = bindtags.index("Text")
        bindtags.insert(i+1, "CustomText")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))

        # set a binding that will fire whenever a 
        # self-inserting key is pressed
        self.bind_class("CustomText", "<Key>", self.OnKey)

    def OnKey(self, event):
        # we are assuming this is called whenever 
        # a character is inserted. Apply or remove
        # each tag depending on the state of the checkbutton
        for tag in self.parent.tag_vars.keys():
            use_tag = self.parent.tag_vars[tag].get()
            if use_tag:
                self.tag_add(tag, "insert-1c", "insert")
            else:
                self.tag_remove(tag, "insert-1c", "insert")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I finally made up my mind and was able to insert this code in mine, seems to work! A small problem however was that moving the cursor around dragged the current format over the characters. I put a < if event.char!='': > at the beginning of OnKey, what do you think?

Comment: @alessandro: if I had to guess, it sounds like your code is calling OnKey for every event rather than just for key presses. You should fix that, rather than put in a hack to work around this fact.

Comment: mmmm I dont think so: it behaves like this even running your code! In fact it was in yours that I first tried the event.char test

Comment: @alessandro: Ok, I see what you're saying now. By "move the cursor" you mean you're using the arrow keys. Yes, in that case, you would want to explicitly check for non-inserting keys such as arrow keys.

Comment: one last bit of help (or maybe should I start a new question...) I just saw that other keypresses create problems (e.g. backspace), so I have to code a way to let it pass thru just printable chars... think that "event.char in string.printable" would be ok?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Bryan, but your approach seems to me too much complicated, and I'm not so eager to start writing bindings for what's missing - *paste* as an example!

I simply wrote down the following, and it seems to work

```
        l=text.tag_names('insert')
        if l==() or l[0]!='b':   # select bold
          text.insert(INSERT, '  ', 'b' )
          text.mark_set('insert', 'insert-1c')
        else:                    # deselect bold
          text.insert(INSERT, ' ' )
          text.tag_remove ('b','insert-1c') 
          text.mark_set('insert', 'insert-1c')
```

My only remaining problem is that I didnt find yet a way not to insert an additional space when selecting bold - but I can live with it...

alessandro

Comment: since my own answer (this one) just got a downvote, whoever did it care to comment about why? I assure you, dear sir, that it works!

Comment: ... no answer, so I'll just confirm (after many days using it) that my solution WORKS, so I'll accept it as answer, and leave it at that.

Comment: The down-vote was likely because Bryan put a lot of effort into providing you with a thorough answer, and then you didn't even upvote it; AND then you simply took the information he gave you and answered your own question. Ouch... +1 Bryan.

Comment: sorry for that, I still am a very poor Tkinter-er, and frankly I was unable to even understand Bryan's answer... sorry everybody!

Comment: @alessandro: I downvoted for the simple reason that this doesn't answer the question. If someone else has the same problem as you, IMO this answer won't be helpful to them. If they take your advice they will maybe solve their first problem, but now they have another problem which is that extra space you don't know how to get rid of.