# intercept any kinf of text deletion in a text frame

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I intercept any deletion of text in my Tkinter program?

Up to now I bound `<Delete>, <Cancel>, <BackSpace>`, but I don't know how to check when my user presses a key while having a selection made - leading to the selected text deletion.

I already have in my program the class `MyText`, with the `OnKey` method, suggested here
[Apply tags in a text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659069/apply-tags-in-a-text-widget/7663455#7663455)
by Bryan Oakley , but the `OnKey` method fires **after** the user pressed the key, so if I check there if a selection exists I find none.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? Are you trying to create sections of text that can't be deleted, or do you intend to do something before or after the text is deleted?

Comment: hi Bryan! I coded in my wiki some outliner capabilities, with autonumbering of the headers. So I have to detect if the user has deleted a header, to be able to trigger a recount by the autonumber code

Answer (score 0):

I should recommend to you use http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm the selection tag, to know what is the selection, put that in an attribute of the class, and look at it when the event OnKey is raised

Comment: That's what I thought too! Unfortunately I dont know exactly where to put the check for the SEL tag. I would need something firing after the user presses a key, but before the key is inserted